# How can I make sure that the state of the counter is unique for each userid when incrementing/decrementing?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, debugging

I have a practice web app I'm working on where I'm trying to mimic Instagram's like system.

With my current code below - the increment/decrement works however, it's incrementing/decrementing in global fashion.

In other words, if I click on user A's photo to increment its like count, that works fine.

Afterwards, if I click on user B's photo, it doesn't increment.  Instead, it decrements.

Then, if I click on  user C's photo it increments

and so on....

It seems like the state of likes is being shared for all users which's incorrect

I'd like the like/dislike system to follow Instagram's but can't quite seem to nail it down.  Below is all the code that's making all of this happen.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

`Gallery.js`:

```
const [isLikedClicked, setIsLikeClicked]                      = useState(false);
const [isDislikeClicked, setIsDislikeClicked]                 = useState(false);
const [userLikes, setUserLikes]                               = useState(null);
const [currentUserClicks, setCurrentUserClicks]               = useState(null);

const handleLikesBasedOnUserId = (likedPhotoUserId) => {
    if(currentUserClicks >= 1) {
        setCurrentUserClicks(currentUserClicks - 1);
        setIsDislikeClicked(true);
        handleDislike(likedPhotoUserId);
    } else {
        setCurrentUserClicks(currentUserClicks + 1);
        setIsLikeClicked(true);
        handleLike(likedPhotoUserId);
    }

};

const handleLike = (likedPhotoUserId) => {
    const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/like';

    const headers = {
        "Accept": 'application/json',
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`
    };

    let data = {
        'UserID': likedPhotoUserId
    };

    axios.post(url, data, {headers})
        .then(resp => {
            setUserLikes(resp.data.userLikes);
        }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });

};

const handleDislike = (likedPhotoUserId) => {
    const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/dislike';

    const headers = {
        "Accept": 'application/json',
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`
    };

    let data = {
        'UserID': likedPhotoUserId
    };

    axios.post(url, data, {headers})
        .then(resp => {
            setUserLikes(resp.data.userLikes);
        }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });

};

return (
    <>
        <div className="main">
            <ul className="cards">
                {
                    gridData.map((photos) => {
                        return <Grid
                            likes={photos.likes}
                            src={photos.url}
                            currentUserClicks={currentUserClicks}
                            onClick={handleLikesBasedOnUserId}
                            isLikedClicked={isLikedClicked}
                            userId={photos.UserID}
                        />
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </>
);
```

`Grid.js`:

```
const [likes, setLikes] = useState(props.likes);
const [likeValue, setLikeValue] = useState(null);

return (
    <>
        <li className="cards_item">
            <div>
                <div className="card_image">
                    <img src={props.src} alt="Photo" className="gallery-img" onClick={() => props.onClick(props.userId, props.isLikedClicked ? setLikeValue(props.user) : setLikes(props.likes + 1))}/>
                </div>
                <span style={{display: 'none'}}>{props.currentUserClicks}</span>
                <h5 className="likes">Likes: {likes}</h5>
            </div>
        </li>
    </>
);
```

backend controller action:

```
public function handleLike(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $userId                                  = $request->get('UserID');
        Uploads::where(['UserID' => $userId])->update(['likes' => DB::raw('likes + 1')]);
        $getUserLikes                            = $this->__usersRepository->getUserLikes($userId);
        $userLikes                               = $getUserLikes[0]->likes;

        return [
            'UserID'                             => $userId,
            'userLikes'                          => $userLikes,
        ];
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Log::error($e->getMessage());
        throw new \Exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e);
    }

}

public function handleDislike(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $userId                                  = $request->get('UserID');
        Uploads::where(['UserID' => $userId])->update(['likes' => DB::raw('likes - 1')]);
        $getUserLikes                            = $this->__usersRepository->getUserLikes($userId);
        $userLikes                               = $getUserLikes[0]->likes;

        return [
            'UserID'                             => $userId,
            'userLikes'                          => $userLikes
        ];
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Log::error($e->getMessage());
        throw new \Exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e);
    }

}
```

Comment: what is the Instagram like system? does it mean that likes on a photo doesn't increment the number of likes on the photo but rather a total number of likes of a user (yep some people don't use insta :P)? I am actually a bit confused by why the likes are associated to a UserId and not a photo id

Answer (score 0):

You seem to associate likes to photos.UserId so for the rest of this answer I will assume that this works because there is only one photo per user and the UserId is actually a photo id (let's say a profile picture).

The initial issue you described comes from your `handleLikesBasedOnUserId` function. If `currentUserClicks` is 1 then it will be set to 0, if it is 0, then it will be set to 1. That's why you keep alternatively like/dislike on each click.

To avoid this a bit of structure refactor is required. I will mainly focus on the frontend part.

Let's have a look at the data structure: is it relevant to have a `currentUserClicks` variable? Actually no. You don't really care about how many times the user clicked in total. What you want to know is for each photo, did the user like the photo?

Similarly `isLikedClicked`, `isDislikedClicked` and `userLikes` (from what I understand it's the number of likes a specific photo has?) are only applicable for 1 photo while you have multiple photos on the grid.

Knowing this, you should consider dropping those states, and think of `userLikedPhotos` which should be a dictionary {[photoId: string]: boolean} or even just a Set of liked photo ids. For your current user, this would be the photos he liked. And it would provide all the information you need, onClick on a photo, if the photoId is in the `userLikedPhotos` then it means that you are performing an unlike action. If it's not in the `userLikedPhotos` (or if userLikes[photoId] === false) then you will perform a like action.

So your code could look like this:

```
const [userLikedPhotos, setUserLikedPhotos] = useState({});  

const handleLikesBasedOnUserId = (likedPhotoUserId) => {
    if(userLikedPhotos[likedPhotoUserId]) {
        // unlike
        delete userLikedPhotos[likePhotoUserId];
        // optimistic UI update. Might get reverted if the backend call fails
        gridData.find(photo => photo.userId === likedPhotoUserId).likes--;
        // ignore backend for now
        // handleDislike(likedPhotoUserId);
    } else {
        // like
        userLikedPhotos[likePhotoUserId] = true;
        // optimistic UI update. Might get reverted if the backend call fails
        gridData.find(photo => photo.userId === likedPhotoUserId).likes++;
        // ignore backend for now
        // handleLike(likedPhotoUserId);
    }
    // we spread the userLikedPhotos to create a new object and force a rendering
    setUserLikedPhotos({...userLikedPhotos});
};

return (
    <>
        <div className="main">
            <ul className="cards">
                {
                    gridData.map((photos) => {
                        return <Grid
                            likes={photos.likes}
                            src={photos.url}
                            onClick={handleLikesBasedOnUserId}
                            userId={photos.UserID}
                            isLikedByCurrentUser={!!userLikedPhotos[photos.UserId]}
                        />
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </>
);
```

```
return (
    <>
        <li className="cards_item">
            <div>
                <div className="card_image">
                    <img src={props.src} alt="Photo" className="gallery-img" onClick={() => props.onClick(props.userId)}/>
                </div>
                <h5 className="likes">Likes: {props.likes}</h5>
            </div>
        </li>
    </>
);
```

Regarding the backend side, I think that you shouldn't store the likes number but rather the list of users who liked a particular photo, the length of this list would be number of likes. This way if the user refreshes the page, you will be able to retrieve which photos he already liked.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried your suggestion but I get error in the `if(userLikes.has(likedPhotoUserId) {}` that says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'has')`.  It looks like `has()` needs to be used with Sets.  I tried switching it to `if(userLikes === likedPhotoUserId)` but on each click it just increments (likes) the photo indefinitely.  It ignores dislike.

Comment: indeed, it's because I was hesitating between a Set and an object, also there was a typo in the variable name. I updated my comment, the condition should be `if (userLikedPhotos[likedPhotoUserId]){}`